# Auto-reloading WAR in Jetty standalone

Tags: jetty

I have a WAR deployed to Jetty 9.0.0.M3. I am trying to figure out what I need to set in my context in order to be able to have it reloaded every time I upload an updated war file (without having to restart Jetty).

I had a look at the docs, but I'm afraid I couldn't find what I was looking for. I only know how to do this with the embedded Jetty Maven plugin, but not with the standalone.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is in the deployer.  You need to wire up the deployment manager functionality and have it manage the starting of the webapp.

http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/tree/jetty-deploy/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/deploy/providers/WebAppProvider.java

The jetty xml files are effectively a thin skin over java so look the following xml file which is what jetty uses for the traditional webapp startup of our distribution.

http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/tree/jetty-deploy/src/main/config/etc/jetty-deploy.xml

This ought to get you fixed up.

Comment: Hm... Okay, so I changed my jetty-deploy.xml to look like that. What else do I appear to need to have do? I mean -- I did that and no auto-reloading is happening.

Comment: This appears to only work, if I make a dummy change to the context. Why would I want to do that? I am uploading an updated WAR file to the server, shouldn't it be picking file size changes to the WAR file itself? Is there something I need to change in my context file? I am not quite getting it, or I'm doing something wrong. Could you please further clarify things for me? Thanks! :)

Comment: I ended up making my script touch the context file, which is ridiculous, but does the job. Any suggestions concerning how to do it right, would be more that welcome! :)

Comment: if you are using a context xml file to deploy then you have to touch the context file, if you just drop a war file in the directory monitored by the deploy provider (with a scanning frequency) then it should detect the war file change and redeploy.  We merged the context xml and war file directories with jetty-9.

Comment: Well, I am using Jetty Stable 9.0.0.M3 and if I only change the war file, the changes are not getting picked up. Only if I touch the context.xml, (which is something I found out about after digging around forums). Perhaps the documentation should be updated a bit and/or a bug/change request needs to be filed, as one would normally expect that modifying the WAR file would suffice. I've literally copied the jetty-deploy.xml you showed me, just to make sure I have fully followed your advice.

Comment: if you have a context xml file, that that is what has to be touched for restarting...if you don't have a context file and just have a war file then that changing should be all that requires a reload...if this isn't working please open a bug at bugs.eclipse.org under RT/Jetty

Comment: fyi, I just tested this on the M4 release we have staged and it works fine, I just 'touch xref-proxy.war' and that war reloaded fine.